# Tuberías en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una duda con la librería `subprocess`:

¿Porque al momento de capturar la salida de la terminal ya sea en `Popen()` o en `subprocess.run()` hay que dar al argumento `stdout` el valor de `subprocess.PIPE` para capturar la salida correctamente?

Según se `subprocess.PIPE` es una tubería, pero ¿Que es una tubería según la librería `subprocess` o según `python`? y ¿Porque justamente hay que utilizar tuberías para capturar la salida de la terminal?

No e encontrado mucha información sobre que son las tuberías exactamente.

---

***De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Empezando por el principio, tenemos tres argumentos del constructor de `subprocess.Popen` íntimamente relacionados con tu pregunta que son `stdin`, `stdout` y `stderr`. Como su nombre indican permiten especificar que queremos hacer con la salida, la entrada y la salida de errores estándares de nuestro subproceso.

Los valores válidos son:

- `None`: no hay redirección alguna. Se heredan directamente del proceso padre. Es el valor por defecto.
- Un descriptor de archivo existente.
- Un objeto de archivo existente: podemos redirigir directamente a un archivo abierto vía `open` por ejemplo:

  ```
  import subprocess

  with open("output.txt", 'w') as fout:
      subprocess.run(["python", "-m", "pip", "freeze"], stdout=fout, encoding="utf-8")
  ```
- `subprocess.DEVNULL`: se utiliza el archivo especial del sistema `os.devnull`. La finalidad es generalmente ocultar e ignorar la salida.
- `subprocess.PIPE`: indica que debe crearse una nueva tubería (pipeline) para el proceso hijo.

Ahora llega la pregunta, ¿qué es una tubería?

Las tuberías no son algo propio de Python, es un invento muy antiguo cuyo padre conceptual es  Douglas McIlro y que luego fue implementado en los inicios del sistema UNIX allá por los años 70. Se dio cuenta que en la consola una gran parte del tiempo simplemente se pasaba la salida de un proceso a la entrada de otro de forma encadenada. A día de hoy, son una parte fundamental de UNIX y Linux por extensión y han sido implementadas en otros sistemas operativos.

Una tubería  no es más que una forma muy simple de redireccionar la salida estándar de un programa hacia la entrada estándar de otro. En la consola linux esto se hace usando el símbolo `|` (pipe), por ejemplo:

```
$ ps -a | sort
```

La línea anterior obtiene los procesos que están corriendo en el sistema (comando `ps`) y redirecciona su salida a la entrada de `sort` para que los ordene.

Imaginate una tubería (pipe) de agua (datos) con varias bombas intercaladas (procesos). Al igual que en una tubería física, el primer byte que entra es el primero que sale por el otro extremo, es lo que se conoce como FIFO (First In First Out). Al igual que una tubería física, son técnicamente unidireccionales, no puedes hacer pasar agua en ambas direcciones a la vez (algunos SO implementaron pipes bidireccionales, pero eso es otro tema).

Hay dos tipos de tuberías:

### Anónimas

Son creados por un proceso padre y **ambos puntos finales (descriptores de archivo) están en la memoria**. Normalmente, el padre crea el subproceso y pasa la tuberías o las tuberías al proceso hijo conectando  los dos procesos a través de ellas y que puede servir como un canal de comunicaciones entre procesos.

Después de la creación del proceso uno de ellos normalmente se cerrará con el extremo gravable de su copia de la tubería y el otro proceso cerrará el extremo complementario (legible). En ese punto, cada proceso tiene solo un extremo de la tubería, siendo uno el proceso escritor y el otro el lector. Obviamente, podemos crear un par de tuberías y hacer la comunicación bidireccional y segura.

Hay varias formas de implementar pipelines, en *nix una tubería anónima no es más que un bloque de memoria o buffer en el kernel, que es leído y escrito por  procesos. Lógicamente tiene un tamaño limitado (64KiB de tamaño en Linux si mal no recuerdo). Si la salida de un proceso es muy extensa y en el otro extremo el otro proceso no consume a un ritmo adecuado. Esto puede ocasionar un bloqueo infinito por ejemplo si se usa `Popen.wait` y el proceso que escribe en la tubería genera muchos datos, ya que el proceso escritor puede quedar eternamente esperando a que el núcleo le deje escribir en un buffer lleno.

### Con nombre

Se les suele denominar FIFO, aunque cualquier tubería como se ha comentado son FIFOs.
**Una tubería con nombre se abre como un archivo**, en modo de lectura o escritura, y se usan las llamadas normales del sistema de archivos para leer o escribir.

A diferencia de las anónimas, tienen un nombre, ocupando una entrada en el sistema de ficheros y se usa dicho nombre para acceder a ellas. Además pueden interconectar dos procesos sin relación alguna, es decir, no tienen que tratarse de un proceso y un subproceso. A diferencia de las anónimas existen hasta que son borrados explícitamente, como cualquier fichero, que es lo que en esencia son con algunos matices.

---

En definitiva, volviendo a Python y subprocess, lo que permiten las tuberías es comunicar el proceso padre con sus procesos hijos. De esta forma, puedes obtener la salida estándar o de errores del proceso hijo en tu proceso padre y simultáneamente enviar vía stdin información al proceso hijo. Obviamente hay más formas de comunicar procesos, entre ellas la colas (que normalmente se implementan sobre tuberías, pero permiten tener varios procesos consumiendo y escribiendo por ejemplo)